# How to send JSONArray as params and recieve JSONObject as response

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I have an API that takes a JSONArray as params and it gives a JSONObject as a response. The API is working fine but giving an error

```
    com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest.parseNetworkResponse
```

as I receive the response.

```
JsonArrayRequest volleyRequest= new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                params, res -> {
            try {
                Log.d("TAG", "PostApiMethod: "+res);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("TAG", "PostApiMethod: ", e);
            }

        }, error -> {

            Log.e(TAG, "PostApiMethod: ", error);
            }

        }) {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
            }
        };

        VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(volleyRequest);
```

Is there any way to do this while using Volley.

Comment: can you edit question set JSONArray structure

Answer (score 0):

you can use `StringRequest` and convert JSONArray to String as parameters and get result as String and map string to `JSONObject` like this code

```
JSONArray jsonBody=new JSONArray();
 try {
 /// add jSONObject inside JSONArray as example 
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
  jsonObject.put("id",1);
  jsonObject.put("name","test");
  jsonBody.put(jsonObject);
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
     @Override
     public void onResponse(String response) {
        textView.setText(response.toString());
        try {
           JSONObject object=new JSONObject(response);
           // do every thing using json object
        } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
  }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
     @Override
     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.d("error",error.toString());
     }
  }){
    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        try {
            return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        String responseString = "";
        if (response != null) {
            responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
            // can get more details such as response.headers
        }
        return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    }
};
```

I recommended using retrofit library instead of Volley